# regex :strange results when using \1

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In order to manage a df, I'm applying `df['sum1'] = df['sum'].str.replace(r'.+(.+).+\1', '.+\1', regex=True)` in order to eliminate the duplicate of record in "sum"

```
    sum                                                             sum1      Target
8   Chiaro Gallo (blabla) (blabla)                                  Che)      Chiaro Gallo (blabla)
9   Ricard Michaeln ()                                              Rhan      Ricard Michaeln ()
10  Marco Liu (Hong Kong Stock Co Ltd) Hong Kong Stock Co Ltd       MarkLtd)  Marco Liu (Hong Kong Stock Co Ltd)
15  Rafiq (Kkska Traning Co (p) Ltd) Kkska Traning Co (p) Ltd       RgLtd     Rafiq (Kkska Traning Co (p) Ltd)
    
    ......
```

.. but I'm obtaining such strange result in "sum1"

Comment: What do you want to be in `sum1` instead?

Comment: 1) make the replacement a raw string i.e. use `r'\1'`, and 2) please also include the expected output.

Comment: yes sorry. I've edited the df. Sorry for alignment hope is clear

Comment: Try `df['Target'] = df['sum'].str.replace(r'\((.*)\).*?\(?\1\)?', r'(\1)', regex=True)`. And for the `sum1`, you can use the same regex in `.str.extract`.

Comment: Dziekuje Wiktor. It works fine... but how is "hermetic" python.. its doesn't vibe in the right wave to me..!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df['Target'] = df['sum'].str.replace(r'\((.*)\).*?\(?\1\)?', r'(\1)', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZIMjW/1). *Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\(?` - an optional `(` char
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `\)?` - an optional `)` char

To get the `sum1` column, you can use the same regex (it can even be a bit shortened) in `.str.extract`:

```py
df['sum1'] = df['sum'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\).*?\1', expand=False)
```

Comment: ya, I almost know the raw instructions of regex from Perl  ..but what I find complex in python is its seams more like german language: to use its power, need to squizze up together 2 or even much more different words (statemets) into a single long long word, that value like a whole frase (instruction block)... Avoid to slick into an error in this environment, is complex to me, yet.